# AWS IoT : Fleet indexing settings through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot, aws-sam

I want to enable **Fleet indexing settings**  in AWS IoT Service.

I can enable this manually. Is there any way through which this can be automated, while deploying my Serverless stack?

Can we use Cloudformation or SAM for enabling Fleet indexing settings?

Any documentation, examples will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time this is not possible. The only AWS IoT resources integrated with CloudFormation at this time of writing Things, Policies, Certificates, and Rules.

One way is using the AWS IoT SDK to call the Fleet Indexing APIs in your initialization scripts.

- Call GetIndexingConfiguration to see if Fleet Indexing is turned on and at the correct setting
- If not, then call UpdateIndexingConfiguration to configure what you'd like indexed.

Comment: We used AWS CLI to enable the Fleet Indexing. This command we included in our Makefile